# How to bind an observableArray properties with another dom element

Tags: knockout.js

Please take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/sLeh8f42/

What is the best way to achieve 'one way binding' from all 'Full Name' textbox in table to checkboxs list ?

For now, by clicking the Add button it only add a new row with empty textboxs.

JS:

```
function Person(id, fullname) {

    return { Id: id, FullName: fullname };
}  

    var FullName = function (fullname, checked) {

            var self = this;
            self.FullName = ko.observable(fullname);
            self.Checked = ko.observable(!!checked);

            self.Checked.subscribe(function () {
                alert(self.FullName() + " is " + self.Checked());
            });
        }

    function ViewModel() {

            var self = this;
            self.PersonArray = ko.observableArray([new Person("1", "Jackie CHAN")]);

            self.Names = ko.computed(function () {
                var arr = [];
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.PersonArray(), function (person) {

                    arr.push(new FullName(person.FullName, false));
                });

                return arr;
            });

            self.AddPerson = function () {

                self.PersonArray.push(new Person("", ""));
            };

            self.RemovePerson = function () {

                self.PersonArray.remove(this);
            };       
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please clearly explain what you are trying to achieve. What are you expecting add to do instead?

Comment: I am expecting that after adding a new row and on change of FullName, the new checkbox label must be renamed with FullName value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Names` and `PersonArray` just use PersonArray and make person use observables.

```
function Person(id, fullname, checked) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(id);
    self.FullName = ko.observable(fullname);
    self.Checked = ko.observable(checked);

    self.Checked.subscribe(function () {
        alert(self.FullName() + " is " + self.Checked());
    });
}  

function ViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.PersonArray = ko.observableArray([new Person("1", "Jackie CHAN", false)]);

    self.AddPerson = function () {

        self.PersonArray.push(new Person("", "", false));
    };

    self.RemovePerson = function () {

        self.PersonArray.remove(this);
    };       
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```
<div data-bind="foreach: PersonArray">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Checked" />
        <label data-bind="text: FullName"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/079t70mj/)